# Route handler in express is not invoking anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, fetch

I have made a simple textbox which accepts

> Youtube Video URL

which slices it's video ID and use **fetch** to send data to my express server. I am using Youtube Data API v3

```js
//after clicking button sends data
//input fields are defined already.
const sendData = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const filterUrl = input2.value.indexOf('&') != -1 ? input2.value.slice(0, input2.value.indexOf('&')) : input2.value;
  const url = new URL(filterUrl).searchParams.get("v");
  fetch('/', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        urlname: url.toString()
      })
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Here is my Express Handler :

```js
//defined routes and PARAMETER variable is globally defined
app.route('/')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render('container/index', {
      title: 'Hello User!',
      content: 'Welcome to youtube Comment viewer'
    });
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    console.log("hello")
    PARAMETER = req.body.urlname;
    console.log(PARAMETER);
    res.redirect('/randomCommentView');
  });


//get request 
app.get('/randomCommentView', (req, res) => {
  console.log("inside");
  Comments(PARAMETER)
    .then((data) => {
      res.render('container/comment', {
        Comment: 'fgfg'
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      if (err) res.status(404).render('container/index', {
        notFound: `Your request couldn't be completed ERR: ${err}`
      })
    })
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

But when i submit my Youtube video url, The page stays on the same route.
Here's the  image of my output:
 [image]

So it seems like the  routes are being called but the page URL is not changing in the web browser .Does anyone know the possible reason for this.
Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using javascript to make your request, only the javascript will follow your redirection.

What you can do is instead of sending a redirection from the server, send a special code that will trigger a manual redirection (`window.location.href = ...`) in your client-side javascript code.

Comment: i tried using window.location.href =" http://localhost:3000/randomCommentView" ... in the then() response but nothing happened.. This time it didn't even console.log("inside") in /randomCommentView route

Comment: and btw i removed the res.redirect("/randomCommentView") from the post route and added the client side redirection.

Comment: Thanks...I was doing res.redirect('/randomCommentView') from route('/');